# Allocating memory to a structure and pointer to a structure

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, structure

This is my structure definition

```
struct node
{
  int value;
  struct node *next;
}
```

I tried allocating memory using this

```
struct node *head1=(node *)(malloc(sizeof(struct node)));
```

and this

```
struct node *head2=(node *)(malloc(sizeof(struct node *)));
```

First one is allocating memory equal to the size of "node" and second one allocate memory equal to the size of a pointer.
But both of them works perfectly well for me.
I mean i am able to access

```
head1-> value
```

and

```
head2->value
```

are they both the same.?

Comment: are u able to assign and access head2->next?

Comment: Why do not you use the `new` keyword in c++?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they're not the same.

The first one has enough memory allocated to accommodate a full structure, and the second only has enough memory for a pointer. By doing `head2->value` you're accessing unallocated memory and will cause undefined behavior.

In fact you could "use" `head2->value` without allocating any memory (and without assigning any value to `head2`). You won't get a compile time error, and you might even not notice that at runtime, but if you have a large enough application you will eventually see weird things start to happen.

Answer (score 1):

No, only the first one is correct.

In the second case you allocate less memory than your data structure is occupying. When you are accessing `value`, you are perfectly fine, because the `value` is at the beginning of your `struct`, and is in what you allocated. Accessing `next` on the other hand will use memory beyond what you allocated. Deceptively, it is also very likely to work, due to how memory allocations work. In most cases the memory given to you will be somewhere in the middle of a page allocated to your process, and accesses within pages that belong to your process do not result in a crash, so if you try to read or write to `next`, it, in most cases, will appear to work (in rare cases, though, your allocation might happen to be at the end of the page, and access to `next` will crash in that case). However, that will not be memory allocated to your object, and might easily be memory used by something else. So, writing to `next` might end up corrupting some other objects you have allocated.

To summarize, the second allocation is wrong, even if it appears to work.